# How to handle Multiple Base Path in RestAssured API Testing Framework?

Tags: rest-assured

In my case, I have multiple Base basePath.

Eg: Base URI- >    http://reg10xx.cwx.local/API/Admin

```
  BasePath1->/User

 EndPoint->/List
```

The problem arises here.

Base URI->  http://reg10xx.cwx.local/API/Admin

BasePath2->/Organisation

```
 EndPoint->/Roles.
```

Here is my case problem is with BasePath 1 and Base Path 2.

As in TestBase.java Class in Before Suite I have used

```
RestAssured.baseURI = configProperties.getBaseURI();
RestAssured.basePath = configProperties.getBasePath();
```

now I want to set my 2nd base path then is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of here is to set the base URL path at the test case/helper method level rather than setting it at the class level.

Example:

```
RequestSpecBuilder build;
build = new RequestSpecBuilder();
build.setBaseUri ("https://maps.googleapis.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is yourbaseurl it , but you can parameterize  yhe baseurl .
Then in Basepath mention the path which is common for both Admin and roles .
After that pass the path which completes the URI  example -roles

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://reg10xx.cwx.local/";
    RestAssured.basePath = "API;


    Response admin= get("Admin");
    Response roles= get("Roles");
```